# Using SoupStrainer with lambda expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Given the following html with three `a` tags:

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a class="lister__item cf lister__item--upsell lister__item--has-ribbon brand-highlight" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""
```

I want to create a SoupStrainer instance that pares down `html_doc`, filtering on `a` tags where the `class` attribute contains 'lister__item'.

I can do this without a SoupStrainer as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='a' and 'lister__item' in tag.get('class'))
```

How can I mimic this with a SoupStrainer instance that is passed to `parse_only` of the `BeautifulSoup` object?  I.e.

```
strainer = SoupStrainer(lambda tag: tag.name=='a' and 'lister__item' in tag.get('class'))
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser', parse_only=strainer)
# TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what exactly is done but it is easy to get a solution by some trickiness. See what's passed to the lambda callable first by printing all `*args`:

```
strainer = bs4.SoupStrainer(lambda *args: print(args))
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser', parse_only=strainer)
('html', {})
('head', {})
('title', {})
('body', {})
('p', {'class': 'title'})
('b', {})
('p', {'class': 'story'})
('a', {'class': 'sister', 'id': 'link1'})
('a', {'class': 'lister__item cf lister__item--upsell lister__item--has-ribbon brand-highlight', 'id': 'link2'})
('a', {'class': 'sister', 'id': 'link3'})
('p', {'class': 'story'})
```

and now adapt with your `lambda` (with the difference that one is of type `BeautifulSoup` and the other beeing `element.Tag`:

```
strainer = bs4.SoupStrainer(lambda tag_name, d: tag_name == 'a' and 'lister__item' in d['class'])
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser', parse_only=strainer)
```

`soup` now contains the same result:

```
>>> soup
<a class="lister__item cf lister__item--upsell lister__item--has-ribbon brand-highlight" id="link2">Lacie</a>
```

Comment: One issue that I should have noted.  Not all of my `a` tags have a `class` attribute so I get a KeyError.  Playing around with `hasattr` in the lambda now but otherwise your answer looks good. Updated question to reflect.

Comment: @BradSolomon instead of `hasattr` use `d.get('class', [])` for the same effect.